# ReadXML+add To MySQL Xstream+ StaxEventItemReader + Spring Batch +Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am new to Spring boot along with spring batch and trying to sort one of my project where I need to read an xml and place the values in Mysql db. I am trying to figure out while referring to similar issues from web but still not able to figure out the error:

Here is SpringBoot Looks Like:

Is it something related to version of Spring boot I am using. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.
pom.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pankaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBatchXmlToMySql</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBatchXmlToMySql</name>
    <description>SpringBatchXmlToMySql</description>
    <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>mysql</groupId>
             <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
             <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
             
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.prpoperties

```
    spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springbatch
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mypwd
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
 
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:data.sql
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Batch Configuration.java

```
  package com.pankaj;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.ItemPreparedStatementSetter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller;
import com.pankaj.model.User;


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

 @Autowired
 public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
 
 @Autowired
 public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
 
 @Autowired
 public DataSource dataSource;
 

 @Bean
 public DataSource dataSource() {
  final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
  dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
  dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springbatch");
  dataSource.setUsername("root");
  dataSource.setPassword("mypwd");
  return dataSource;
  
 }
 
 @Bean
 public StaxEventItemReader<User> reader(){
  
  XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
  Map<String, Class<?>>  aliases = new HashMap<>();
  aliases.put("user", User.class);
  
  xStreamMarshaller.setAliases(aliases);
  
  StaxEventItemReader<User> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<User>();
  reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("user.xml"));
  reader.setFragmentRootElementName("user");
  reader.setUnmarshaller(xStreamMarshaller);
  
  return reader;
 }
 
 
 @Bean
 public JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer(){
  JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<User>();
  writer.setSql("insert into user(id,name) values(?, ?)");
  writer.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(new UserItemPreparedStmSetter());
  writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
  return writer;
 }
 
 private class UserItemPreparedStmSetter implements ItemPreparedStatementSetter<User>{

  @Override
  public void setValues(User user, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
   ps.setInt(1, user.getId());
   ps.setString(2, user.getName());
  }
  
 }
 
 @Bean
 public Step step1() {
  return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
    .<User, User> chunk(10)
    .reader(reader())
    .writer(writer())
    .build();
 }
 
 @Bean
 public Job importUserJob() {
  return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
    .flow(step1())
    .end()
    .build();
    
 }
}
```

User.Java

```
    package com.pankaj.model;

public class User 
{
     private Integer id;
     private String name;
     
     public Integer getId() {
      return id;
     }
     public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
     }
     public String getName() {
      return name;
     }
     public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
     }

}

user.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
 <user>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>Jack Rutorial demo 1</name>
 </user>
 <user>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>Jack Rutorial demo 2</name>
 </user>
 <user>
  <id>3</id>
  <name>Jack Rutorial demo 3</name>
 </user>
</users>
```

error:

.   ____          _            __ _ _

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v2.5.4)[0;39m

[2m2021-09-14 00:15:51.669[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13468[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.SpringBatchXmlToMySqlApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting SpringBatchXmlToMySqlApplication using Java 16.0.1 on MDDN-LAP-TECH with PID 13468 (C:\Users\mac008433\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite\SpringBatchXmlToMySql\target\classes started by MAC008433 in C:\Users\mac008433\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite\SpringBatchXmlToMySql)
[2m2021-09-14 00:15:51.671[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13468[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.SpringBatchXmlToMySqlApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The following profiles are active: @spring.profiles.active@
[2m2021-09-14 00:15:52.997[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13468[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No database type set, using meta data indicating: MYSQL
[2m2021-09-14 00:15:53.168[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13468[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
[2m2021-09-14 00:15:53.248[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13468[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.SpringBatchXmlToMySqlApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started SpringBatchXmlToMySqlApplication in 1.904 seconds (JVM running for 3.103)
[2m2021-09-14 00:15:53.249[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13468[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherApplicationRunner  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Running default command line with: []
[2m2021-09-14 00:15:54.787[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13468[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=11}]
[2m2021-09-14 00:15:55.789[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13468[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Executing step: [step1]
[2m2021-09-14 00:15:56.288[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m13468[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Encountered an error executing step step1 in job importUserJob

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:990) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:593) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller$1.<init>(XStreamMarshaller.java:432) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.constructXStream(XStreamMarshaller.java:431) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.buildXStream(XStreamMarshaller.java:419) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.util.function.SingletonSupplier.get(SingletonSupplier.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.util.function.SingletonSupplier.obtain(SingletonSupplier.java:115) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.getXStream(XStreamMarshaller.java:624) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.doUnmarshal(XStreamMarshaller.java:827) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.unmarshalXmlStreamReader(XStreamMarshaller.java:787) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.unmarshalXmlEventReader(XStreamMarshaller.java:778) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.oxm.support.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshalStaxSource(AbstractMarshaller.java:412) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.oxm.support.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractMarshaller.java:355) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.doRead(StaxEventItemReader.java:273) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:93) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:99) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:180) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:118) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:71) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy49.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:772) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.pankaj.SpringBatchXmlToMySqlApplication.main(SpringBatchXmlToMySqlApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @957e06
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:40) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>(TreeMapConverter.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    ... 65 common frames omitted

[2m2021-09-14 00:15:56.384[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13468[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Step: [step1] executed in 594ms
[2m2021-09-14 00:15:56.841[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13468[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=11}] and the following status: [FAILED] in 1s821ms




enter code here



enter code here
enter code here
```

Comment: tried Jaxb2Marshaller xStreamMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
  but with luck. I am having one of those days.

Comment: Your sample works with Java 8 with no issues. The issue is related to using Xstream with Java 11, see https://github.com/x-stream/xstream/issues/137.

Comment: Thanks Mahmood. That's what I thought. I can see that I can change java version from pom itself to work. I will see and report.